# Unable to run tests due to browser or driver version issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am automating a web application using Selenium 4.3.0. It's a java project and not maven. And, not using webdrivermanager. I am getting frequently the below error while running the automation tests through chrome browser. Similar problem with edge also.

---

```
    Warning: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 107, so returning the closest version found: 103.
    org.openqa.selenium.devtools.cdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
    INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 107 of 103.
```

---

Comment: This shouldn't prevent you from running tests.  Do you receive any other exceptions/errors?  Does the browser launch?

Answer (score 0):

The CDP version supported by selenium 4.3.0 is:

```
v4.3.0
======

* Supported CDP versions: 85, 101, 102, 103
```

Link : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG

In your case, I think the google chrome version is `107` and selenium can support only up to `103`.

You have 2 options, either to downgrade the chrome version to `103`. Or upgrade selenium version to at least `v4.6.0` or higher.